# Chef Inspec - How to Read Custom Properties in Files

Tags: chef-infra, inspec

I'm currently using Chef Inspec and want to read the content within some of my SH files. How can I get ChefInspec to read some of the properties contained within them:

Ex:

```
ex_sh_file = location/ex_file.sh'
describe bash(ex_sh_file) do
   it { should be_writable }
   its('custom property' ) { should eq 5 }
end
```

Is there a way for InSpec to reconfigure this? Would I have to make it read from a JSON file?

Comment: Hi. Welcome here. Please edit the question and make it [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This is one of the important requirements for a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).